# How to cumsum() / cumcount() starting from an offset - the highest group id already allocated and saved?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

1. Precondition: Data from a dataframe (**dfold**) is already saved to CSV file. The data looks like so:

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['timestamp','base']
data =      [['2022-10-14 11:47:38',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:39',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:40',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:41',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:42',200],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:43',200],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:44',300],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:45',300]]
    
dfold = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
dfold.set_index(['timestamp'],inplace=True)
dfold['pbase'] = dfold['base'].shift(1).fillna(0)
dfold['pbase'] = dfold['pbase'].astype(int)
dfold['groupid'] = (dfold['base']!=dfold['pbase']).cumsum()
print('Print dfold\n',dfold)
```

```
Print dfold:
                      base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:38   100      0        1
2022-10-14 11:47:39   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:40   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:41   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    100        2
2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    200        2
2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    200        3
2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    300        3
```

2. Data is logically grouped based on a column - groupid. Group id is created using cumsum(). The problem is that each new set of messages is again assigned groupids' starting from 1 instead of the highest no already assigned. This is illustrated by using a new dataframe (dfnew). The prior data in dataframe (dfold) is already saved to CSV file.

```
columns2 = ['timestamp','base']
data2 =      [['2022-10-14 11:47:46',400],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:47',400],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:48',500],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:49',500]]
    
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(data=data2,columns=columns2)
dfnew.set_index(['timestamp'],inplace=True)
dfnew['pbase'] = dfnew['base'].shift(1).fillna(0)
dfnew['pbase'] = dfnew['pbase'].astype(int)
dfnew['groupid'] = (dfnew['base']!=dfnew['pbase']).cumsum()
print('Print dfnew\n',dfnew)
```

```
Print dfnew:
                      base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:46   400      0        1
2022-10-14 11:47:47   400    400        1
2022-10-14 11:47:48   500    400        2
2022-10-14 11:47:49   500    500        2
```

3. The highest groupid allocated is retrieved like so:

```
maxgroupid = dfold['groupid'].max()
print('Max group id stored is: ',maxgroupid)
```

```
Max group id stored is: 3
```

4. Problem: How do I reallocate unique group id - in this case starting with 4 - to the new messages in new dataframe (dfnew)? The expected result in dfnew is given below:

```
Expected result in dfnew:
                      base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:46   400      0        4
2022-10-14 11:47:47   400    400        4
2022-10-14 11:47:48   500    400        5
2022-10-14 11:47:49   500    500        5
```

5. What I have tried to do to accomplish this but not succeeded so far:

```
grpnew = dfnew.groupby('groupid',as_index=True).max()
print('Grouped dfnew:\n',grpnew)
grpnew['newgroupid'] = range(maxgroupid + 1, maxgroupid + 1 + len(grpnew))
print('New groupid added to grouped dfnew:\n',grpnew)
dfboth = pd.merge(dfnew,grpnew,on='groupid',how='outer')
print(dfboth)
```

```
**Grouped dfnew:**
          base  pbase
groupid             
1         400    400
2         500    500

**New groupid added to grouped dfnew:**
          base  pbase  newgroupid
groupid                         
1         400    400           4
2         500    500           5

**Merged output (unable to merge timestamp index)**
   base_x  pbase_x  groupid  base_y  pbase_y  newgroupid
0     400        0        1     400      400           4
1     400      400        1     400      400           4
2     500      400        2     500      500           5
3     500      500        2     500      500           5
```

5. **Issues:**

(a) I am unable to get the timestamp index in the merged dataframe (**dfboth**)

(b) I am unsure if this is the most efficient method performance-wise

Please help in resolving (5) stated above. The expected result is shown in step 4 above (dfnew with new group ids - 4 and 5). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating it. If you have access to `dfold` at each iteration, why not just add the previous max group id?

```py
columns = ["timestamp", "base"]
data = [
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:38", 100],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:39", 100],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:40", 100],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:41", 100],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:42", 200],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:43", 200],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:44", 300],
    ["2022-10-14 11:47:45", 300],
]

dfold = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
offset = dfold.groupid.max() - 1 if "groupid" in dfold else 0
dfold["groupid"] = dfold.base.diff().ne(0).cumsum() + offset
```

### Iteration 1

```
             timestamp  base  groupid
0  2022-10-14 11:47:38   100        1
1  2022-10-14 11:47:39   100        1
2  2022-10-14 11:47:40   100        1
3  2022-10-14 11:47:41   100        1
4  2022-10-14 11:47:42   200        2
5  2022-10-14 11:47:43   200        2
6  2022-10-14 11:47:44   300        3
7  2022-10-14 11:47:45   300        3
```

### Iteration 2

```
             timestamp  base  groupid
0  2022-10-14 11:47:38   100        3
1  2022-10-14 11:47:39   100        3
2  2022-10-14 11:47:40   100        3
3  2022-10-14 11:47:41   100        3
4  2022-10-14 11:47:42   200        4
5  2022-10-14 11:47:43   200        4
6  2022-10-14 11:47:44   300        5
7  2022-10-14 11:47:45   300        5
```

### Iteration N

```
             timestamp  base  groupid
0  2022-10-14 11:47:38   100        N
1  2022-10-14 11:47:39   100        N
2  2022-10-14 11:47:40   100        N
3  2022-10-14 11:47:41   100        N
4  2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    N + 1
5  2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    N + 1
6  2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    N + 2
7  2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    N + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and posting here for future reference. The idea is NOT to use cumsum(). Instead, use max() method, boolean series and then transform method as shown below:

**STEP 1: Create dataframe (dfold) with initial values:**

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ['timestamp','base']
data =      [['2022-10-14 11:47:38',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:39',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:40',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:41',100],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:42',200],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:43',200],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:44',300],
                ['2022-10-14 11:47:45',300]]
    
dfold = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)
dfold.set_index(['timestamp'],inplace=True)
dfold['pbase'] = dfold['base'].shift(1).fillna(0)
dfold['pbase'] = dfold['pbase'].astype(int)
dfold['groupid'] = 0 # initialize new column
print('Print dfold\n',dfold)

Print dfold
                      base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:38   100      0        0
2022-10-14 11:47:39   100    100        0
2022-10-14 11:47:40   100    100        0
2022-10-14 11:47:41   100    100        0
2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    100        0
2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    200        0
2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    200        0
2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    300        0
```

**STEP 2: Create boolean series and use transform method with user-defined function as shown below**

```
start = dfold.groupid.max()
print(start)

def getvalue(x):
    global start
    if x:
        start+=1
    else:
        start
    return start

dfold['groupid'] = (dfold['base']!=dfold['pbase']).transform(func = lambda x: getvalue(x))
print(dfold)
```

**Output:**
**Iteration 1:**

```
                     base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:38   100      0        1
2022-10-14 11:47:39   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:40   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:41   100    100        1
2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    100        2
2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    200        2
2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    200        3
2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    300        3
```

**Iteration 2:**

```
                     base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:38   100      0        4
2022-10-14 11:47:39   100    100        4
2022-10-14 11:47:40   100    100        4
2022-10-14 11:47:41   100    100        4
2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    100        5
2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    200        5
2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    200        6
2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    300        6
```

**Iteration 3:**

```
                     base  pbase  groupid
timestamp                                
2022-10-14 11:47:38   100      0        7
2022-10-14 11:47:39   100    100        7
2022-10-14 11:47:40   100    100        7
2022-10-14 11:47:41   100    100        7
2022-10-14 11:47:42   200    100        8
2022-10-14 11:47:43   200    200        8
2022-10-14 11:47:44   300    200        9
2022-10-14 11:47:45   300    300        9
```